# How do I properly format this YAML snippet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I have a cloudformation snippet that looks roughly like this :

```
  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Type :  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties : 
       InstanceId: !Ref ContainerSG
       GroupDescription :  "ECS Containers Security Group"
       VpcId :  !Sub {{resolve:ssm:/ca/config/network/vpc_id:${ParamVersion}}}
       GroupName :  !Sub   ${Env}-${ServiceName}-sg
       SecurityGroupIngress :
        -  IpProtocol :  tcp
           FromPort :  8080
           ToPort :  8080
           CidrIp :  10.49.63.0/24
        -  IpProtocol :  tcp
           FromPort :  8080
           ToPort :  8080
           CidrIp :  10.93.0.0/16
        -  IpProtocol :  tcp
           FromPort :  8080
           ToPort :  8080
           CidrIp :  10.97.0.0/16
        -  IpProtocol :  tcp
           FromPort :  8080
           ToPort :  8080
           CidrIp :  10.50.128.0/21
        -  IpProtocol :  tcp
           FromPort :  8080
           ToPort :  8080
           CidrIp :  10.50.144.0/24
        -  IpProtocol :  tcp
           FromPort :  8080
           ToPort :  8080
           CidrIp :  172.25.0.0/16
```

What am I doing wrong here? I get the following error:

```
Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed.
```

Can someone help me to resolve this one? Is there perhaps a workaround I have not considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML requires consistent spacing for indention.  Make sure you are use the same amount of spacing for each indent.  The example you posted indents 2 spaces for some, 3 spaces for others.  If you edit a YAML file in a modern IDE (i.e. [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)), it should format and do the indention for you so you don't have the think about it.

Also, the VpcId line is not correct, the `{{resolve:}}` mechanism can't be combined with `!Sub` to parameterize the value presently, this has to be hardcoded.  You may want to use the [SSM Parameter types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types) instead or just hardcode this.

```
ContainerSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    InstanceId: !Ref ContainerSG
    GroupDescription: "ECS Containers Security Group"
    VpcId: {{resolve:ssm:/ca/config/network/vpc_id:1}}
    GroupName: !Sub ${Env}-${ServiceName}-sg
    SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 8080
        ToPort: 8080
        CidrIp: 10.49.63.0/24
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 8080
        ToPort: 8080
        CidrIp: 10.93.0.0/16
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 8080
        ToPort: 8080
        CidrIp: 10.97.0.0/16
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 8080
        ToPort: 8080
        CidrIp: 10.50.128.0/21
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 8080
        ToPort: 8080
        CidrIp: 10.50.144.0/24
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 8080
        ToPort: 8080
        CidrIp: 172.25.0.0/16
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input and explanation. I've tried using your hard-coded example but I'm getting a format error still ([/Resources/ContainerSecurityGroup/Type/VpcId/Fn::Sub] map keys must be strings; received a map instead). Do you know why this is?

Comment: sorry, i had typo (I didn't test), i removed the !Sub from the VpcID in my answer, try that

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, but I'm still getting a format error ([/Resources/ContainerSecurityGroup/Type/VpcId] map keys must be strings; received a map instead). I'm a newcomer to CloudFormation so this is really confusing, would happen to know how to solve this?

Comment: This is not true. Resolve works with Sub, you just need to wrap the resolve part in quotes.